# Why does DROP PRIMARY KEY affects ALL table rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, primary-key, rdbms

```
mysql> select count(*) from employees;  
+----------+  
| count(*) |  
+----------+  
|    10000 |  
+----------+  
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

I don't understand the following:
If I drop the primary key it says that **all** of the rows in my table are affected:

```
mysql> alter table employees drop primary key;  
Query OK, 10000 rows affected (0.33 sec)  
Records: 10000  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

But if I create the primary key 0 rows are affected.

```
mysql> alter table employees  
    -> add constraint employees_pk primary key(subsidiary_id, employee_id);  
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.43 sec)  
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

I don't understand this. I understand that when I create the primary key a `UNIQUE INDEX` is created as a separate datastructure, but why on `DROP PRIMARY KEY` all rows are affected and none on the creation?

Comment: If the table has no PRIMARY KEY or suitable UNIQUE index, InnoDB internally generates a hidden clustered index on a synthetic column containing row ID values.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html I`m not sure if this is what affects all rows.

Comment: @Mihai:I think it creates a composite index over **all** columns in that case

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the rows those have been affected are the ones belonging to the index. Since the index gets dropped.

Comment: But why are the rows affected on dropping the index.If there is some association between each row and the index, wouldn't the create index also show the same behavior?

Comment: Well, index has its own rows. But about creating the index, i thought the same thing, creating index also creates rows with the same number   as the table. Not having an answer to that really.